# static constant Vs define directive

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to define a constant in my .m file. I can see two options here:

```
static NSString *const kMyLabel = @"myLabel";

#define kMyLabel @"myLabel"
```

Which one is the best? Is there any issues with using static here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that you can take the address of the variable, while you cannot take the address of a constant string expression (which is what the macro reduces to). I prefer to avoid `#define`s when possible, so I'd go with the former, but that's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part it doesn't matter from a usage perspective. But there is a slight advantage to using the static method in that each usage of the `kMyLabel` constant in code will be a pointer to the exact same object (in most cases) whereas the `#define` method will create copies of the string. I believe that in more recent compilers, it is intelligent enough to do the `defines` as one object, but to be safe, I would just use the `static` method.

Comment: Neither will create copies of the string. Constant strings are unique within a compilation unit.